# Simple server-side validation using php

Tags: php, validation

i have a problem with the validation my input and select fields.
If the inputs are empty and click on submit the warning "this field is required" appears.

But when i fill the ClientID input and the selection box is empty the validation will fail. Or invers, when the select box is selected and the input is empty.

here my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>  
<html>
<head>
<style>
.error {color: #FF0000;}
</style>
</head>
<body>  

<?php

$nameErr = $katalogErr = $selectKatalog = "";
$kdn = "";

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
  if (empty($_POST["kdn"])) {
    $nameErr = "This field is required";
  } else {
    $kdn = test_input($_POST["kdn"]);
    // check if kdn only contains letters, numbers and whitespace
    if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9 ]*$/", $kdn)) {
      $nameErr = "Only letters, numbers and white space allowed"; 
    }
  }

  if($_POST["selectKatalog"] == 'default'){
      $katalogErr = "This field is required";
  }
  else {
    $selectKatalog = $_POST["selectKatalog"];
  }
}

function test_input($data) {
    $data = trim($data);
    $data = stripslashes($data);
    $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
    return $data;
}
?>

<h2>Order a Catalog</h2>
<p><span class="error">* required field.</span></p>
<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">  
  ClientID: <input type="text" name="kdn">
  <span class="error">* <?php echo $nameErr;?></span>
  <br><br>
  Catalog: <select name="selectKatalog">
              <option value="default">Bitte wählen:</option>
              <option value="Catalog1">Catalog1</option>
              <option value="Catalog2">Catalog2</option>
              <option value="Catalog3">Catalog3</option>
           </select>
  <span class="error">* <?php echo $katalogErr;?></span>
  <br><br>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">  
</form>

<?php
echo "<h2>Your Input:</h2>";
echo $kdn;
echo "<br>";
echo $selectKatalog;
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: _"when i fill the ClientID input and the selection box is empty the validation will fail. "_ what do you mean by "the selection box is empty" - no values selected at all? As per your code, the validation should not fail on the `<select>` unless the selected option is "default". Are you sure it's failing in that case? Have you debugged what values are actually being sent to the server (check your browser's network tab, and/or `var_dump` them in PHP.

Comment: As for _" Or invers, when the select box is selected and the input is empty."_ It should definitely fail in that case, that's what your code is set up to do.

Comment: the code shouldn't be submited when one of them is filled/choosen. but this is not that happening. when i fill the input field and the selext box option is default i get a result of the input field. I souldn't get any result.

Comment: Your code is absolutely fine. Not sure what error you are trying to explain.

Comment: @GregOstry if any one of them is failing and you dont want to allow to submit the form then that validation needs to be done in JS at client side. Not on server side.

Comment: okey i thought i can do this with php.

Comment: you can validate either side

Comment: are you using composer? I have written a form lib that deals with population, filtration, validation, rendering, and error handling. `composer require delboy1978uk/form` if interested and I'll give you a hand with it if you like

Comment: @GregOstry PHP validation will only run after the form is submitted, as you've noticed. But you can still use it to display errors and stop further processing, e.g. saving to database etc. To enhance the user experience you can always add JavaScript validation _as well_, to prevent the form being submitted at all if there are errors. However, you should _never_ rely on JS validation alone to check the user's input - it's trivial to disable it or bypass it using the browser settings. So for a complete, secure and user-friendly solution you really need both types of validation

Comment: If you only have time/resources to build and maintain one set of rules, you should _always_ go with the server-side (PHP) validation, for security and robustness. There are also tools around I think which can do things like auto-generate JS/HTML5 client-side rules based on rules defined on the server. Certainly that exists for ASP.NET apps, not sure what there is for PHP, but might be worth searching.

Comment: @delboy1978uk "you can validate either side". That's not particularly good advice from a security point of view. See my comments above. You should start with server-side validation as a must, and then move on to client-side as a nice-to-have.

Comment: I agree! However I wasn't addressing security, just pointing out that the guy who said we must validate it in javascript is wrong to say so. Server side validation is the better choice, as you say!